# PHP not echoing hidden element value returned by xpath

Tags: php, xpath

Below is the form element that I want to scrape:

```
<input id="form-c989bfc426f882cb8664a471c5e485e2" type="hidden" value="form-c989bfc426f882cb8664a471c5e485e2" name="form_build_id">
```

My goal is to get the value `form-c989bfc426f882cb8664a471c5e485e2`
and I'm using my usual functions below:

```
$x = my_curl_function($url); // the page where form has the hidden fields

$y = my_xpath_function($x);    

$z = $y->query("//input[starts-with(@id, 'form-')]");
```

I know the functions above works fine because `$z` has a length which is not zero. and if i dumped the value of `$z`, it would give me the result like below:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#5 (1) { ["length"]=> int(3) }
```

The main problem is that i cannot echoed the value like I would normally do like so:

```
if ($z->length > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $z->length; $i++) {
        echo $z->item($i)->nodeValue;   // should echo the results of $z
    }
}
```

What could be the problem? is it because its a hidden field? if so then why it has value when I dump it. it just don't display and Im puzzled.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thank you.

Comment: Include the markup in your question?

Comment: If you want to access the `value` attribute you should explicitly query it as follows: `$y->query("//input[starts-with(@id, 'form-')]/@value");`.